# Mostrar modal apenas se existir uma sessão ativa

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, django, modal

Quando alguém cadastra seu nome e e-mail eu crio uma sessão e renderizo novamente a página com o nome de quem se cadastrou, porém não estou conseguindo entender como que faço para que na hora que eu renderizo novamente a página apareça um modal.

***views.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from registrations.models import Group

def index(request):
    form = NewsletterForm(request.POST or None)
    group = Group.objects.filter(active=True).first()
    show_modal = False
    content = {'show_modal': show_modal, 'group': group, 'form': form}

    if not group:
        show_modal = True
        content = {'show_modal': show_modal, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'index.html', content)


    if form.is_valid():
        contact = form.save()
        request.session['contact_id'] = contact.id
        request.session.set_expiry(100)

        if 'contact_id' in request.session:
            show_modal_contact = True
            content = {'contact': contact, 'show_modal': show_modal, 'group': group, 'show_modal_contact': show_modal_contact}
            return render(request, 'index.html', content)

        content = {'contact': contact, 'show_modal': show_modal, 'group': group, 'show_modal_contact': show_modal_contact}
        return render(request, 'index.html', content)

    return render(request, 'index.html', content)
```

**Modal que quero que apareça quando apos salvar e renderizar novamente a pagina:**

```
<!-- Modal Contato -->
{% if show_modal_contact %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){

        $(window).load(function(){        
            $('#modal_contato').modal('show');
        });

    }, 1000)
    </script>
{% endif %}

{% if show_modal_contact %}
<div id="modal_contato" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="text-center bottom-border">
                            <img class="img-modal" src="{% static 'images/ilustra3.png' %}" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-modal text-center">Pronto, iremos te avisar assim que abrirem novas turmas</p>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a id="close_modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-estacao">Voltar para Estação Hack Teens</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Até li algo sobre AJAX e tal, porém não consegui colocar em prática, será que vocês conseguem me dar mais essa ajuda?

Comment: Não teria que ter a classe `in` no modal para ele já começar aberto? tipo `class="modal fade in"`

Comment: então @fernandosavio o problema que esse modal só pode ser "aberto" quando a pessoa se cadastrar apos eu usar o comando `contact = form.save()
        request.session['contact_id'] = contact.id
        request.session.set_expiry(100)` basicamente ele é redirecionado ai eu teria uma verificação caso tenha uma sessão significa que ele se cadastrou então ai sim deve mostrar o modal e não quando a pagina carrega

Comment: Essa validação é feita no backend correto? O frontend apenas sabe que se ele receber uma variavel `show_modal_contact` verdadeira o modal deve ser mostrado, não é?

Comment: exato @fernandosavio estou fazendo assim mesmo vou editar aqui o post pra ficar melhor de visualizar

Comment: Então a linha `{% if show_modal_contact %}` só vai enviar o HTML do modal quando for necessário que ele seja mostrado na tela. Como esse modal só vai existir quando ele precisar ser mostrado, ou seja, não vai ficar escondido esperar sua ativação, seria só inserir o `in` mesmo. Já tentou pra ver se o comportamento não é o desejado?

Comment: pior que tentei @fernandosavio como você pode ver ai edição que eu fiz, testei porém não aparece o modal fiz um teste com um _alert_ na função e deu certo, mas com o modal não kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, vendo que da forma que eu estava tentando eu não estava obtendo exito, resolvi o problema usando ajax mesmo, segue o código.

***views.py:***

```js
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
from registrations.models import Group

def index(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    group = Group.objects.filter(active=True).first()
    show_modal = False
    content = {'show_modal': show_modal, 'group': group, 'form': form}

    if not group:
        show_modal = True
        content = {'show_modal': show_modal, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'index.html', content)

    return render(request, 'index.html', content)

def contact(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    form = ContactForm(data)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        contact = Contact.objects.filter(email=data['email']).first()

        if contact:
            return JsonResponse({'contactRegistered': 'O e-mail já esta cadastrado'}, status=400)

        print(data['email']) 
        contact = form.save()   
        return JsonResponse({'success': True})

    return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
```

***main.js:***

```js
const formModal = document.querySelector('#modal_contato');
const modalButton = document.querySelector('#formPorDentro button');
const modalCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#modal_contato button');

modalButton.onclick = showModal;

for(let button of modalCloseButtons){
    button.onclick = dismissModal;
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === formModal) {
        dismissModal();
    }
}

function showModal(){
    formModal.style.display = 'flex';
    setTimeout(() => formModal.style.opacity = 1, 100);
}

function dismissModal(){
    formModal.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(() => formModal.style.display = 'none', 1000);
}

function submitForm(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#formPorDentro input');
    let data = {};
    let csrfToken;

    for(let input of inputs){
        if(input.type === 'text'){
            data[input.name] = input.value;
        }

        if(input.name === 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'){
            csrfToken = input.value;
        }
    }

    toogleVisibleModalContainer('#loading')

    fetch('/registrado', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(formSubmitSuccess)
      .catch(treatErrorResponse);
}

function formSubmitSuccess(response){
    if(response.status === 400){

        response.json().then(treatErrorResponse);
        return;
    }
      
    if(response.status === 200){
        response.json().then(treatSuccessResponse);
        return;
    }
      
      throw 'Invalid response from server';
}

function treatErrorResponse(data){
    let errors = Object.keys(data);
    let contactAlreadyRegistered = document.querySelector('#error');

    if(errors.indexOf('contactRegistered') > -1){
        contactAlreadyRegistered.style.display = 'block';
    }

    toogleVisibleModalContainer('#error');
}

function treatSuccessResponse(){
    toogleVisibleModalContainer('#success');
}

function toogleVisibleModalContainer(containerClass = ''){
    let containers = document.querySelectorAll('#modal_contato .modal-content');
    let activeContainer = document.querySelector(`#modal_contato .modal-content${containerClass}`);

    for(let container of containers){
        container.style.display = 'none';
    }

    activeContainer.style.display = 'block';

}

const sendButton = document.querySelector('#formPorDentro button');

sendButton.onclick = validateForm;

function validateForm(){
    if(validateContact()){
        showModal();
    }
}

function validateContact(){
    let contactEmail = document.querySelector('[name=email]');
    let contactName = document.querySelector('[name=name]');
    
    if(contactEmail.value == ''){
        contactEmail.classList.add('invalid');
    } if (contactName.value == ''){
        contactName.classList.add('invalid');
    } if (contactEmail.value != ''){
        contactEmail.classList.remove('invalid');
    } if (contactName.value != ''){
        contactName.classList.remove('invalid');
    } if(contactEmail.value != '' && contactName.value != ''){        
        submitForm();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

***index.html:***

```html
<!-- Modal Contato -->
    <div id="modal_contato" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content" id="loading">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="text-center bottom-border">
                                <img class="img-modal" src="{% static 'images/loading.gif' %}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content" id="success">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="text-center bottom-border">
                                <img class="img-modal" src="{% static 'images/ilustra3.png' %}" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="text-modal text-center">Pronto, iremos te avisar assim que abrirem novas turmas!!!</p>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-estacao">Voltar para Estação Hack Teens</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content" id="error">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="text-center bottom-border">
                                <img class="img-modal" src="{% static 'images/ilustra3.png' %}" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="text-modal text-center">Já existe alguém cadastrado com esse e-mail</p>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-estacao">Voltar para Estação Hack Teens</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Dessa forma eu consigo fazer o que eu estava precisando.